# 'NPM start' running on a strange URL after vscode crashed

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

My react app ran normally on the URL "http://localhost:3000" before vscode crashed (something about 'memory heap out'). After reopening vscode,

> npm start

runs on the URL "http://localhost:3000/bryansomto/appName" and displays nothing. I tried editing the URL back to the previous working URL (that is, without /bryansomto/appName) from within the browser but the page still displays nothing.

Ps, no error is shown on the terminal from which I run npm start.

This is what my start script in package.json looked like before and after the issue.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node-env-run server --exec nodemon | pino-colada",
    "dev": "run-p server start" },
```

Comment: hm, did you change anything in the json package? Take a look at it and post what is listed in the start attribute.

Comment: I just added the start script from the JSON package @BrentHarris

Comment: looks good. Try looking at the 'homepage' url in the same json package, that might be the ticket to remove anything. Did you also take a look at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths